# Remove index Dataframe pandas

Tags: pandas, csv, dataframe, indexing

I need to remove the dfA index because when I print dfA i have:

```
      Este Mes  Subastas
0   01/01/2018  39
```

And I need:

```
Este Mes  Subastas
01/01/2018  39
```

How can I do that? Because I know if I read the csv file and I write `index=False` but the problem is I convert my original csv and in the first time I need the index to operate and have dfA. I can´t give a name to index and del the column after because this is a restriction 
I will use again the dfA to paste it in a xls but without the index

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('este_mes.csv', sep=',')
df1 = df.groupby(['Fecha'])['Subastas'].sum()
df2 = df1.to_frame().reset_index()

dfA = df2
dfA.columns = ['Este Mes', 'Subastas']
df2 = df2.Subastas
df2.to_csv('este_mes_subastas2.csv', index=False)
```

SOLUTION:

I can do it without remove the index because I need to paste the `dfA` on a `xlsx` so when I did it I set `index=False`and I had the results I was looking for!

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('este_mes.csv', sep=',')
df1 = df.groupby(['Fecha'])['Subastas'].sum()
df2 = df1.to_frame().reset_index()

dfA = df2
dfA.columns = ['Este Mes', 'Subastas']
df2 = df2.Subastas
df2.to_csv('este_mes_subastas2.csv', index=False)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

dfA.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Este Mes x Dia',index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `pd.DataFrame.to_string` method with an argument of `index=False`

```
print(df.to_string(index=False))

Este Mes  Subastas
01/01/2018        39
```

**Note**: I'm not a fan of the resulting formatting.

Comment: yes but i don't want to change the dataframe to a string

Comment: the other way is add headers to `df1`but I don´t know how I can do it